# Plotting with gnuplot/tikz gives weird offset of exactly 0.5

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm plotting some basic high symmetry band structures in plain `tikz`. As you can see the lower limit of each of these functions should be at:

[image: http://imgur.com/vf7r4rs]

The plotted function instead shows a different lower limit (see picture below), with a discrepancy of exactly `.5`. Where is this coming from? I couldn't find any error in the code that could lead to this difference.

[image: http://imgur.com/yP8cwBN]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgffor}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,1) -- (3.25*pi,1);
    \draw[->] (0,1) -- (0,6.7);
    \node[below] at (0,1) {$\Gamma$};
    \node[above] at (0,6.7) {$E_k$ (eV)};
    \draw[-] (pi,6.7) -- (pi,1) node[below] {$\mathrm{X}$};
    \draw[-] (2*pi,6.7) -- (2*pi,1) node[below] {$\mathrm{M}$};
    \draw[-] (3*pi,6.7) -- (3*pi,1) node[below] {$\Gamma$};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
    \node at (-.3,\i) {$\mathllap{\i}$};
    \draw[-] (-.15,\i) -- (0,\i);
    }
    \draw[domain=0:pi] plot function{((2)+(-1))/2+.5*sqrt(((2)-(-1))*((2)-(-1))+16*1.5*((sin(x/2))*(sin(x/2))))};
    \draw[domain=pi:2*pi] plot function{((2)+(-1))/2+.5*sqrt(((2)-(-1))*((2)-(-1))+16*1.5*((sin(pi/2))*(sin(pi/2))+((sin((x-pi)/2))*(sin((x-pi)/2)))))};
    \draw[domain=2*pi:3*pi] plot[id=sin] function{((2)+(-1))/2+.5*sqrt(((2)-(-1))*((2)-(-1))+16*1.5*((sin(pi/2))*(sin(pi/2))+((sin((x-pi)/2))*(sin((x-pi)/2)))-((sin((x)/2))*(sin((x)/2)))))};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you closing the square root right on you function?

Comment: _An attempt was made to fix mismatched parentheses..._ Might the same mismatch exist in your code?

Comment: @Sigur I've updated with the right brackets in Wolfram

Comment: @PaulGessler The brackets match, now both in the Wolfram picture as well as the code.

Comment: In case you didn't tried: if you replace the constant part of the function by `0.5+` it will work. But in any case, it is a good question.

Comment: @1010011010: This happens because `gnuplot` uses integer division. Replacing `((2)+(-1))/2` with `((2.)+(-1.))/2.` and you'll get the correct result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jake pointed out, `gnuplot` uses integer division causing the expression `((2)+(1))/2` to be inequal to `((2.)+(1.))/2.`, with a difference between the two expressions of `0.5`.